# How Does a Router Enable Inter-Home Device Connections without Internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

[This Wirecutter article](https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/blog/modem-vs-router/) claims "A router ... allows [wireless devices] to talk to one another without having to do so over the internet". How is this possible? Would the experiment to validate this is possible be the following?

1. Disconnect the Modem, but keep the router on
2. Get my roommate's public IP address for their laptop
3. Send a web request there?

Is this simply an example of client-server LAN? [https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/switches/what-is-a-lan-local-area-network.html#~what-it-is](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/switches/what-is-a-lan-local-area-network.html#%7Ewhat-it-is)

Comment: Your title uses the term "inter-home" but nowhere is that mentioned in the article. Btw even something as simple as a switch (or even a single network cable) allows devices to talk to one another without the internet. You don't even need a router.

Answer (score 3):

If you and your roommate are using the same router, then you are both on
the same LAN that is created by the router. You have both local IP addresses,
but not public IP (public means internet).

For this to work, the router needs to be a DHCP server, meaning that it
hands out IP addresses to the local devices.

So yes, you can carry out the experiment that you described in your post.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, a [router creates a local area network](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/technology-explained-how-does-a-router-work/), LAN, with each device connected to the router given a unique, *strictly local*, IP address. For example the router itself might have IP 196.168.1.1, the first device connected to it 196.168.1.2, the next 196.168.1.3, usw.

The router also connects to the outside world, i.e., the Internet, through a modem. The router, *and all devices in the LAN*, is seen by the outside world by a different IP address, temporarily leased to the router by your ISP.

Therefore, assuming it doesn't disable the router due to its operating system (yes, the router has its own computer), disconnecting the modem should *not* disable communication between devices on the LAN. That said, disconnecting the modem *might* cause some issue, so I'd not recommend testing that.

You can see current and past WiFi connections on your system. For Windows, for example, use Nirsoft's free [Wireless Network Watcher](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_watcher.html).

[image: Wireless Network Watcher]

Note that a router is *not* required for direct PC-to-PC (peer-to-peer) communication, such as an [*ad hoc* WiFi or Ethernet network](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101591&seqNum=2). You can  be 1,000 km from the nearest access point and still have two devices talk directly to each other.